# SQL Database approach - I need your suggestion

Tags: php, sql, database

Hello everyone and thank you for viewing this question.

**Since someone asked what i am doing this for, here is the answer:**
*An artist asked me to make him a web app to store all his new concerts etc.. Now, when it comes to add the Instruments, artists etc, i could have 10 instruments, or maybe 100.. Everything is set into a form.. Some data is fixed like location, time etc, but this other fields are added dynamically using DOM..*

I am building a system in which the user set up a form to be stored on a database like:

```
Name,Surname,field_1
//Lets say that this is the "fixed" part of the form
//But the user should be able to add 'n' other fields with no limit
//Therefore my problem is that i would end up with a row made of, lets say,
//4 colums
//And another one of, maybe, 100 columns
//
//Then i will need to access these rows, and row one should have 4 cols, row two 100..
//This can't be done in a "traditional" way since each row should have the
//same amount of cols
//
//I thought to create a new table for each submission 
//but this doesn't really make that much sense to me..
//
//Storing all the possible fields in a single one and then 
//access them through an array ? That would require too much, even since my fields
//should have the possibility to be edited..
//Each field is a mixture of variables then, like 
//field1:a=12,field2:b=18.. too complex
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: what is this? your homework?

Comment: An artist asked me to make him a web app to store all his new concerts etc.. Now, when it comes to add the Instruments, artists etc, i could have 10 instruments, or maybe 100.. Everything is set into a form.. Some data is fixed like location, time etc, but this other fields are added dynamically using DOM..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go the one field approach. You could have three columns, `Name`, `Surname`, and `field_values`. In the `field_values` column, store a PHP [`serialized`](http://php.net/serialize) string of an array representing what would otherwise be your columns. For example, running:

```
array(
    ['col1'] => 'val',
    ['col2'] => 'val1',
    ['col3'] => 'val2',
    ['col4'] => 'val3'
)
```

through `serialize()` would give you:

```
a:4:{s:4:"col1";s:3:"val";s:4:"col2";s:4:"val1";s:4:"col3";s:4:"val2";s:4:"col4";s:4:"val3";}
```

and you can take this value and run it back through `unserialize()` to restore your array and use it however you need to. Loading/saving data within this array is no more difficult than changing values in the array before serializing it and then saving it to the `field_values` column.

With this method you can have as many or few 'columns' as you need with no need for a ton of columns or tables.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would personally create a new table for each user, with new row inserted for ever new custom field. You must have a master table containing table names of each user table to access the data within later.